# Do the 2013 Time Capsules work as a NAS drive?

Tags: time-capsule

Can I partition the 2013 Time Capsules to use some of their storage as a network drive?

Comment: How does nobody know the answer to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The internal drive gets shared as one volume. You would need to layer user access controls to set up folders for different uses within the same share.

But you can attach an external drive to the USB port and access that as shared storage from any peripheral on your network. Those show up as separate volumes when you use the stock Apple firmware on the Time Capsule.

Comment: Sorry my question was poorly phrased.  So you can use the time capsule as a share drive and also as a backup destination, correct?  You just can't partition them at the disk level but the time capsule will show up in Finder as a shared drive and you can just treat it as a network drive?

Comment: If you attach an external hard drive to the USB port on the Time Capsule it will show up as a shared drive that you can just treat as network attached storage. But the internal drive can only be used for Time Machine backups.

Comment: Thanks, that sucks!  I have a 1TB NAS drive right now with 3 years worth of backups of my MacBook (512MB HDD) so I think even the 2TB TimeCapsule will be overkill.  Maybe I'll just get an Airport Extreme...

Answer (score 0):

Can we revisit this a minute?

What does this mean?

> "You would need to layer user access controls to set up folders for
>   different uses within the same share."

I have a 128 SSD and a 256 SSD on two MBA's
No way i need 2 TB to that up.  I wanted to use it a NAS for stuff i don't really care to back up.  Sounds like I can do that.

Does not make sense to me to put a Drive attached via USB (2.0 nonetheless) to use for this when i have lots of space in the time capsule.

Thanks.

Edgar